# Multiple sources for kinesis firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-kpl, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Basically, I have servers writing data into kinesis streams in multiple regions. 
I would want to read from those streams and dump the data into a single S3 bucket, preferably consolidated one.

I was hoping to make kinesis firehose read from multiple kinesis streams and write to S3. Is this possible?
If not, should I be running multiple KCL applications reading from individual streams and writing into multiple firehose?
Or is there an alternate architecture. Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by combining multiple source streams into a single firehose? Are you looking to reduce costs or simply comingle records? If the latter, are you familiar with how Firehose writes records to S3? And if yes, how would you expect it to be different using multiple stream sources?